# Returned roth 401k check

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-401k

After leaving a company for a new job, a Roth check was sent to me. Is there any tax consequences if this money is not reinvested? (It's a small amount of only  $100)

Comment: Did you have a Roth 401K? Regardless, it's probably not a big deal since it's after tax money...

Comment: Yes it was a Roth 401k

Answer (score 2):

The earnings portion will be taxed at your marginal tax rate + 10% penalty. If the total is $100, then the earnings portion is probably not very significant for this to be a concern.

But it's something you could put into a Roth IRA and let it compound with the rest of your retirement savings. Depending on your age, the compounding effect of $100 invested early enough tax free can be thousands of dollars at retirement.

i.e. You have 60 days to deposit it into a Roth IRA. Don't let that pass you by.